# How to calculate UITextView first baseline position relatively to the origin

Tags: ios, uitextview

How can I calculate `UITextView` first baseline position?

[image]

I tried calculating it this way:

```
self.textView.font!.descender + self.textView.font!.leading
```

However, the value I'm getting is not correct. Any ideas, hints?

Comment: `descender` if the offset from the baseline, certainly it should not been involved in the calculation. `leading` or `lineHeight` *might* be enough?

Comment: I think is `self.textView.font?.ascender`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation zcui93 gives, `font.ascender` will give you the offset to the baseline within the font.  To get the baseline of the font within the `UITextView` you need to add in `textContainerInset.top`:

```
extension UITextView {
    func firstBaseline() -> CGFloat {
        let font = self.font ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())
        return font.ascender + textContainerInset.top
    }
}
```

There's a little bit of assumption here in defaulting to the system font if no font is set, but I'm not sure what a better guess would be.

Running the following in the playground will demonstrate the effect:

```
class Container : UITextView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSaveGState(context)

        let containerRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, textContainerInset)
        UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, containerRect)

        let baseline = firstBaseline()

        UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.75).setStroke()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, containerRect.origin.x, baseline)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, containerRect.origin.x + containerRect.width, baseline)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

        super.drawRect(rect)
    }
}

let textView = Container(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())
textView.text = "My Text"
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: what about the indent on the left? I can not find a solution ...

Answer (score 4):

There is a diagram from the Apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html)

[image: Figure 9-4 Font metrics]

From my understanding, `font.descender + font.leading` gives the distance between the first baseline and starting of the second line.

I would *imagine* `font.lineHeight` would give you the right number, if `UITextField` doesn't have a secret padding.

---

**EDIT**

`UITextField` and `UITextView` shared same `UIFont` property.

For `UITextView`, there's an extra `textContainerInset` can be set.

**EDIT 2**

A further look at the `UITextView` gives more clue about what can be achieved:

It actually has a `textContainer` property, which is a `NSTextContainer`.

> The NSTextContainer class defines a region in which text is laid out. An NSLayoutManager object uses one or more NSTextContainer objects to determine where to break lines, lay out portions of text, and so on.

And it's been used by `layoutManager`, theoretically the padding to the top of  first line of text could be found by `usedRectForTextContainer(_:)`.

I will need to test this once I have a Mac in hand. :)

Comment: You are writing about `UITextField` and I'm asking about `UITextView`. Would it still work? And the problem is that the diagram explains UIFont only. UITextView adds its own top padding.

Comment: Sorry about this, they both share the same `font : UIFont` property, so I believe if one works, the other should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was extending UITextField class and I just wanted to draw a line in the textfield baseline and I succeed with the following chunk:

```
self.svwLine = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,self.frame.size.height+(self.font?.descender)!,self.frame.size.width,2))
self.svwLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.addSubview(self.svwLine)
```